# Deleting a Row from Datatable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, datatables

I used Backbone collection to create a table and applied jquery data-table for pagination. I have an icon to delete the row. When clicked it is deleting from collection but deleted row is still present in data table.

More information:

I have the collection with person details (firstname:Tony). And this data will sit in template "{{firstname}}". In that way I'm setting the entire row in template. Suppose my collection is named as "addedGridRowCollection" to which each individual person detail is set to model(ex:addvisModel) and in turn model is set to collection. Hence the code is as ---

```
var addedVisitorGridView = new AddedVisitorGridView({
  collection: addedGridRowCollection
});
newVisitorLayoutView.gridRegion.show(addedVisitorGridView);
addedVisBasicModel.set("firstname", "Tony");                                                                      addedGridRowCollection.add(addedVisBasicModel);
    applyDataTable(); // applying jquery data table
    $(addedVisitorGridView.el).show();

Now in delete trigger: when I clicked on Delete button,The following is the code I am using:

   var indx= model.get('index');

    var visModel = addedGridRowCollection.findWhere({index: indx});
    addedGridRowCollection.remove(visModel);

here it removes from collection but not from the data-table (Jquery).
```

Comment: You not have two-way data bindings, and means you must manually render your template with changed data. You may use method [on](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) of collection, to handle `'change'` event on collection. Also, could you give an example of the code to be able to accurately answer.

Comment: I have the collection with person details (firstname:Tony). And this data will sit in template "<td>{{firstname}}</td>". In that way I'm setting the entire row in template. Suppose my collection is named as "addedGridRowCollection" to which each individual person detail is set to model(ex:addvisModel) and in turn model is set to collection. Hence the code is as